# Установка Windows XP/Vista с флешки

Tags: windows, windows-xp

Итак. У меня есть ноутбук с Debian и GRUB на борту. Ноутбук не умеет грузиться с DVD. Флешки с Linux вполне грузит. Требуется установить WindowsXP/WindowsVista. Уже пробовал подключать загрузчик установщика через GRUB (ntldr путь_к_заргрузчику). Пробовал загружать разные файлы. Ничего не помогало. В нете нарыл, что для запуска инсталлера winXP с флешки, нужно:

1. Переименовать папку I386
2. Заменить файл, ссылка на который была удалена (был загружен файл на DepositFiles, который файлы удаляет со временем).

А при попытке запустить Windows Vista у меня не может найти файл "/Boot/BCD", хотя он присутствует - я даже специально сделал копию папки boot (переименовал в Boot) копией bcd под названием BCD (изначально было /boot/bcd).

Вопрос: что делать?
P. S. О сохранении линукса речи не идёт - это я уже сам сделаю.

Comment: используйте программу для создание загрузочной флешки `https://rufus.akeo.ie`, и чистые оригинальные образы ОС

Comment: 1. BIOS mode. No EFI.  2. У меня на втором ПК тоже Linux. 3. Gparted+DD делает тоже самое.

Comment: а на втором ПК эта флешка с XP грузится?

Comment: Не тестировал, но на нём тоже GRUB.

Comment: На виртуальной машине образ вполне запускается.

Comment: Есть рабочий, но костыль. Поставить на виртуалку, а потом clonezilla или acronis true image слить на реальное железо. Если "чтоб работало" - то работать будет. Сам так делаею. А если вопрос задан из академического интереса, то тут я пока пас. Надо старые папки порыть.

Comment: Не получился. Перейти с венды на линух помогло. Но не выйдет, если хост - линух. Ведь для формата USB требуется рут.

Comment: я правильно понял задачу, что нужно переустанвоить с linux на winXP?  если так, то вам необходимо установить [это](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/unetbootin),  После поставить свой биос в режим CSM, и собственна все)